# Themes with package igaster

Tags: php, laravel, themes, service-provider

I am now implementing themes in my project.
I have installed igaster/laravel-theme package.

While I can switch themes by changing the default theme in config/themes.php, I have no idea how to change a theme **sitewide** - with a button like this:

```
<a href="set_theme/2">change to 2</a>.
```

The package's author says I need to use a ServiceProvide. 
I created one. 
And now... what?

**Edit: solution**

Based on the answer provided by igaster I made it work - PARTIALLY.
This is a more detailed description of what I did:

In this file:
**App/Providers/themeSelectServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;
use Cookie;
use Request;

class themeSelectServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {



public function register()
{

// for testing purpose I ignore the variable and hardcode the theme's name
//  just in case I test both with and without backslash
// as the namespaces in L5 tends to be a major pain.
// neither one works.



    $theme = Session::get('themeName');

    // $theme = Request::cookie('themeName');

    Session::put('theme', $theme);

    if ($theme == 'Fawkes') {

        \Theme::set('Fawkes');
    }
    if ($theme == 'Seldon') {

        \Theme::set('Seldon');
    }

    else {\Theme::set('Fawkes');}







}

}
```

I have registered the service provider in my **config/app.php** file:

```
'providers' => [
...
    'App\Providers\themeSelectServiceProvider',
```

in my routes file i have this route:

Route::get('set_theme/{themeName}', 'SitewideController@set_theme2');

which leads here:

```
use Response;
use Theme;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;

class SitewideController extends Controller {


public function set_theme2($themeName)
{

\Theme::set('Seldon'); // I tested them one at a time to determine
Theme::set('Seldon');   // if there is a classname issue


if (Theme::find($themeName)) // Is $themeName valid?

{
    return Redirect::to('/')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('themeName', $themeName));
// this is the only way I am able to create a cookie. Facade DOESN'T WORK!
}

    Redirect::url('boooo'); // my error page

}
```

So as of now I am a step forward - the below line in my ServiceProvider changes the theme.

```
    else {\Theme::set('Fawkes');}
```

**The problem which persists:**

Inside the ServiceProvider I cannot read neither any value stored in Session nor any cookie. 
Just for testing purpose i created the

```
Session::put('theme', $theme);
```

But the Session variable was NEVER created - not with Cookie, not with Session.

Please help if possible

Edit 2:

I tried to put in the ServiceProvider the below code:

```
    if(Auth::check()) {
        \Theme::set('Seldon');
    }
```

but it results in blank screen ( I have debug = true).
In log file I see:

> local.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class hash does not exist'

Laravel 4 was developer-friendly and amazing. Laravel 5 is over the hill already. L6 will be unusable, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Sessions in Laravel5 are initiated in the middleware stack you should create your own middleware and place it in the `$middleware` array in `Kernel.php`. This is a sample middleware:

```
class myMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

       $themeName = \Session::get('themeName', 'NONE');

          if(\Theme::exists($themeName))
              \Theme::set($themeName);

           return $next($request);
       }

   }
```

your routes.php could be something like:

```
Route::get('setTheme/{themeName}', function($themeName){
    Session::put('themeName', $themeName);
    return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::get('/', function() {
    return Theme::get();  // display your views here....
});
```

Note that you have to pull the latest version (v1.0.4) for this to work

Comment: I am a step forward. Please check my edited question. 

It seems that I cannot get access to Session or Cookie inside the ServiceProvider.
WIll appreciate any hint. Thx

Comment: After installing 1.0.4  get this error: local.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message 'Theme 'Fawkes' not found' in D:\www\!NiePozwalam\vendor\igaster\laravel-theme\src\Themes.php:50
I reverted to 1.0.3 and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I did exactly that from the very beginning. 
I just got an opinion from an extremely competent guy, that either your package or L5 should be modified to get the job done and my atempts were doomed to fail from the very beginning. 
I am lost with your soltion in Route.php (namely using 'return Theme::get()). Does it mean I need to rewrite all my routes? I have this in routes: Route::get('/', array('as'=>'landingpage','uses'=>'PagesController@landingpage'));
 and in controller method  i have return View::make with  variables and a "compact" statement w/ more variables

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly followed the installation instructions (https://github.com/igaster/laravel-theme), you can change the theme like this:

```
Theme::set('theme-name');
```

If you want to change the theme by clicking a link, you have to store current theme name somewhere. Most probably you don't want to store it in URI, so I advice you to store it in a session.

Comment: I have spent already 3 hours on the problem. L5 is a b... to me, it seems.

Please check out my edit - I boiled down my problem to sth else. Maybe you could find a solution to the ServiceProvider problem.