# Cookies and Session variables work partially inside ServiceProvider

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

This is a fork of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025983/themes-with-package-igaster).
As of now my problem is to get Cookie variable in unhashed form - see point 6 below.

I am unable to  set themes. As for now I have determined by trial and error that inside my ServiceProvider I cannot use cookies nor session variables.

The content of my ServiceProvider looks like this:

**App/Providers/themeSelectServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;
use Cookie;
use Request;
use Auth;

class themeSelectServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {



public function register()
{

// for testing purpose I ignore the variable and hardcode the theme's name
//  just in case I test both with and without backslash
// as the namespaces in L5 tends to be a major pain.
// neither one works.



    $theme = Session::get('themeName');

    // $theme = Request::cookie('themeName');

    Session::put('theme', $theme);
    Session::put('check', 'What the...');

    if ($theme == 'Fawkes') {

        \Theme::set('Fawkes');
    }
    if ($theme == 'Seldon') {

        \Theme::set('Seldon');
    }

    else {\Theme::set('Fawkes');}







}

}
```

I have registered the service provider in my **config/app.php** file:

```
'providers' => [
...
    'App\Providers\themeSelectServiceProvider',
```

The situation is:

1. I can print the Session::get('themeName') in any view anywhere in my app.
2. I can print the Cookie as well - it is seen in views
3. The line

   else {\Theme::set('Fawkes');}

changes the theme - but I need to edit the value (Theme's name) manually to switch between them. the commands in the if conditions are never working.

4. When I try to set a Session value with this line

   Session::put('theme', $theme);

nothing happens. But the

```
Session::put('check', 'What the...');
```

after being declared inside the ServiceProvider, is seen in views.

5. When I play with namespaces declarations, I get errors. Which means that the ServiceProvider content is parsed.

Please help me to solve the issue!

Edit:

So as @igaster says, Session will not work for me. Sad.

Still, the Cookies solution mentioned in igaster/themes readme.md do not work either. I made this test:

6. While in any VIEW file this code

   Request::cookie('themeName');

Produces the cookie's expected value ("Seldon")

when I execute the below code inside ServiceProvider

```
$theme = Request::cookie('themeName');
Session::put('theme', $theme);
```

and then print the Session variable in a VIEW, I get sth like this:

eyJpdiI6IjU0eUF6Y3YwaGdmSEhaTVplS3hyQ1E9PSI4InZhbHVl5oiMWhQY2hYRjZ6YzBmUjRDSjc5amNXUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMTEyYTeNTc0MjM2ZmE5YzA5OWYwYWE5MjE3OTNhYjZkMTU5NmVmZDcwYTg5YyJ9

It seems that the Cookie was not unhashed.

Can anyone tel me what to do in order to get the coded value?

7. Also, in the ServiceProvider I am unable to get the theme value from database
   Usually for a logged user I do this:

   ```
       $ic = Usersetting::where('user_id',Auth::id())->first();
       $theme = $ic->InterfaceComplexity;
       \Theme::set($ic->InterfaceComplexity);
   ```

but here I get blank screen. Same when I use conditional code like this:

```
    if(Auth::check()) {
        \Theme::set('Seldon');
    }
```

> local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler::$charset' in D:\www!NiePozwalam\vendor\symfony\debug\Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler.php:199

Comment: as for point 6: Session can not be used until the `StartSession` middleware is executed, which takes place after the Service Providers are registered & booted. Probably you are getting the encrypted data.... The only way to use cookies or sessions is with a custom middleware. Create one with  `artisan make:middleware myMiddleware`

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are not working inside Service provider because they are initated later in the middleware stack...

You should use a middleware instead

Comment: That's not good, as the Cookie solution does not work either. Please take a look at point 6 which I just added to my initial question above. The reason I tried with Sessions is that Cookies (recomended solution to switch themes) didn't work! Now I know why!

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to a `boot()` method instead. This will be ran when after all service providers have been registered:

```
class ThemeServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $theme = Session::get('theme');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // Register any application services here
    }

}
```

Comment: I added the boot function and inside it $theme = Request::cookie('themeName'); and hard-coded  \Theme::set('Seldon'); and got a strange result. In my view the command Theme::get() gives me 'Seldon', but the theme set is not 'Seldon' but 'Hawkes'.

Comment: @Peter Because cookies are only available from the next request. If you set a cookie, you won’t be able to access it in that same request.

Comment: I know. But in my case  the cookie is set long ago, so it doesn't matter. In the only place I can swich themes - which is  public function register() -I can only get hashed version.

Comment: @Peter If you can do it in the `register()` method then there’s no reason why you can’t do it in the `boot()` method.

Comment: Say this to the Laravel creator. Until now spent 5 hrs on attempt to use sht as simple as themes. I tried all reasonable or unreasonable options with blind trial & error included. anyway - it DOES NOT work, unfortunately. See my first comment - i get inconsistnt result. 
The colosest way to a solution is to make the register() function read cookie properly (unhashed).

Comment: @Peter I’m not sure what the issue is. Surely the user selects the theme, and then theme should take effect on all subsequent page views?

Comment: Cookies are tricky some times as they can not be set if you have any output (ie echo-ing anything) before sending the coockie. Don't dd() anything or interupt the request before completing...